# vertex transitive self answer

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, asking-questions, self-answer

Can I self answer a question I post about examples of connected, vertex transitive graphs? I cannot find anything listing larger ones, and am even less likely to find examples with thoughtful choices of embeddings. However I may have discovered most of them up to about size 12, they're a lot more diverse that people tend to think. Is this something that could be useful to others?

Comment: The important thing to remember, if you choose to post a question you intend to answer, is to post a high-quality question with context: why this topic is of interest to you, your level in math, etc.  If you then answer a well written question (writing it as though you have no answer, and trying to help provide as many details as you can, inviting others for their input, e.g.), I see **no** problems in your posting such a question, and then answering.  Best of luck.

Comment: thank you for the info

Comment: If I were interested enough in that topic, I'd consider posting a Question that asks for resources (literature, software, etc.) on cataloging smallish vertex transitive graphs.  For context your work on (say) cataloging all the vertex transitive graphs of order 5 could be sketched, and the known cases "up to about size 12" would be helpful to supply as a self-answer.  With luck someone will supply a fulsome answer with more links to the subject than you've been able find on your own.

Comment: I'll do the work over the coming days, but I'm no longer sure if I could make a coherent SE question.